# Magento 2.0 and Zapier

Tags: magento2, api

I recently installed Magento-2. I want Zapier to connect to Magento 2.

In Magento 1.9, I simply had to create and account and a role with an API key for Zapier to connect to the application.

Does anyone know the solution for how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Zapir in regards to Magento 2 integration. As of now 7-23-16 Magento 2 is not supported but it is in the works. I'm not sure how long but I'm assuming they base it off demand.

I would urge everyone who wants Zapier for Magento 2 to let them know. This way they will be aware of the demand and prioritize respectively.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Good news! Zapier now fully supports Magento 2.x - You can check out the integration [here](https://zapier.com/zapbook/magento-v2/).